# Add Key pair to remote linux server

Tags: ansible, ssh-keys

I'd like to add a key pair to "tuser" on linux server "Ubuntu 18.04lts" using ansible, just to avoid password based login. 
So I've tryed this way with success in yml playbook file:

```
- name: Set authorized key for tuser
  become: yes
  authorized_key:
    user: tuser
    state: present
    key:  "{{ lookup('file', '/home/rogg/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

well, but when I've tryed to use other location in key:

```
- name: Set authorized key for tuser
  become: yes
  authorized_key:
    user: tuser
    state: present
    key: "{{ role_path }}/files/csbin_keys/id_rsa.pub"
```

I get :

> "msg": "invalid key specified

I've already used {{ role_path }} for copy other files and just works, but in this keys it didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from docs for `authorized_key` module:

> = `key`
>          The SSH public key(s), as a string or (since 1.9) url (https://github.com/username.keys)

In your first example `lookup('file', '/home/rogg/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')` reads the file `/home/rogg/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and feeds its content as `key` value.

In your second example you try to feed file path as `key` value.

Replace it with lookup:

```
lookup('file', role_path+'/files/csbin_keys/id_rsa.pub')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `with_file` option, which reads in the content of a file:

```
- name: Ensure the public key is populated
    authorized_key:
      user: john
      state: present
      key: '{{ item }}'
    with_file:
      - /home/john/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```